# SNMP :snmpwalk response from NAS timeout issue

Tags: linux, network-programming, snmp, nas

I am new to Linux networking.
I am trying to configure SNMP between a Linux pc <--> Switch <--> NAS(Buffalo TS500D).
I have configured  `snmpd` in linux pc and enabled SNMP in NAS. When I checked the query mesasage from linux pc using command

```
$snmpwalk -Os -c MSTTeraStation -v 2c 169.254.213.10
```

I got the response as follow

```
$iso.3.6.1.2.1.1.1.0 = STRING: "BUFFALO TeraStation TS5200D Ver.2.81 (2015/02/17 $12:00:35)"

$iso.3.6.1.2.1.1.2.0 = OID: ccitt.1

....
....

iso.3.6.1.2.1.25.3.2.1.1.1026 = INTEGER: 1026

iso.3.6.1.2.1.25.3.2.1.1.1027 = INTEGER: 1027

Timeout: No Response from 169.254.213.10
$
```

When I again checked the query message I am not getting response anymore for around 10-15 minutes after that getting response as above.

Comment: snmpd = daemon to respond to SNMP request packets.   So am confused why you need it running on the PC, assuming you mean you have installed net-snmp on Linux side to get the walk & get utilities.

Comment: Is this really a programming question? Questions about networking and server administration belong on serverfault.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest install protocol analyzer e.g. [wireshark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireshark)  to see 
what is really going on at the SNMP protocol level

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion .snmpwalk was getting timeout even before getting response from NAS  . I checked with wireshark and verified this. You were also was correct Brian Avery . Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with k1eran. This doesn't seem like an issue with your SNMP request, but rather something else. I would look at Wireshark (use the filter "SNMP" to see only SNMP traffic). First, check if there is a response. If the Buffalo NAS responses more than 1 second after the request is made, then the snmpwalk will have timed out and that will give you the error. If there isn't a response then the NAS either isn't responding to it or isn't receiving it.